# Can we earn reputation by reviewing posts?

Tags: discussion, reputation, review-queues

Recently I reached 2000 reputation on stackoverflow.com.  Now I am able to review posts which are edited by the other users.

So I keep reviewing posts. I want to know:

**Can we earn reputation by reviewing posts?**

**If yes, what are the rules? Is there a min/max limit to the number of reviews for earning reputation?**

Comment: Reviewing is a 'site moderation' task and it is not a Q&A activity. Reputation can be gained only by Q&A activity (and to some extent by approved suggested edits).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

By "score", I'm assuming that you mean "gain reputation"- and you do not gain reputation by completing reviews.

However, you do earn rare badges for completing reviews- You earn a silver badge at 250 reviews and a gold badge at 1000 reviews for each queue.

Please keep in mind, though, that there is a good reason for not incentivizing reviews. We want people to moderate these queues because it is a necessary part of the site. By not incentivizing them, hopefully users think more and spend more time on the review queues because they have no reputation to earn from them.

Comment: Wow! badges! So, instead of gaining reputation I'll have silver or gold badge at particular counts of reviews. Is it one time ? I mean for every 250 reviews I'll get silver and for every 1000 reviews I'll get gold badge ? Is it so ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: it's a one time thing per queue, but make sure to review carefully as you get review-banned very easily if you review incorrectly.

Comment: I again want to stress that you should not review just because you want the badges. Clicking through the "Looks Good" button for each review will get you banned from the queues.

Comment: No No, I skip the reviews which I dont feel correct.

Comment: Anyway I had my answer now. Thank you guys Qantas and Blue Ice. I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto No problem! See you around the site!

Comment: What about 1 reputation for each 5 reviews ? or something like that ?

Comment: So why do we get reputation for edits? I always understood that reputation indicates contribution to the site.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels when you reach 2k reputation you will not get reputation for edit. When you reach 2k **SO** thinks you are mature enough and will contribute with valid and good resources and allows you to reflect your edit instantly without giving you any reputations.

Comment: @krishna I didn't about know that

Comment: @MatthijsWessels check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). It says `suggested edit is accepted: +2 reputation`, when you get 2k reputation, the edits will not be waiting for approval, so you will not get any reputation for edits

Comment: I think reputation gain would make people more motivated to do it.

Comment: Gaining reputation for 'serving the community' (such as review queues, flags, etc.) is a topic that comes up not infrequently here on Meta. While it *may* seem nice to offer 'small' rewards (say, + 50 rep for every 1,000 reviews), would we then need to 'punish' (-50 rep) those who fail audits and get review-banned? It's a can of worms that, IMHO, should be left securely *unopened*.

Comment: @AdrianMole No, we wouldn't punish them. Some people like curating the site better than answering questions(me included).