# Why should a question about gaining reputation for reviewing be on Meta Stack Overflow instead of Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, meta, migration

I noticed [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251123/210336) has been migrated from Stack Exchange to Stack Overflow Meta.

It is about why you don't gain reputation from reviewing. Isn't this a general Stack Exchange issue? Or is this a per site thing? I.e. can I post the same question on a different SE meta?

Comment: I guess because it explicitly mentioned *stackoverflow.com* it was migrated. It's rather poor quality, but it'd be on-topic on *both* sites. Slightly puzzling, that migration, really.

Comment: The original MSE question had the [stackoverflow] tag as well. Tim probably watches the tag for migration candidates

Comment: @Martijn So should it be migrated back?

Comment: Not really, no; it is on-topic here too.

Comment: You can expect a few anomalies and edge cases here and there having to do with [the spin-off of Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250024/the-status-of-the-split). In other words, don't expect every migration to be perfect.

Comment: @Cupcake doesn't mean that we can't correct mistakes right? But I understand that the question is fine here as well.